# vb.net combobox shows only 1 record

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

when i add `cmname` `clname` on `.ValueMember` i'm having error, because im planning to show 3 records in asingle combobox, i.e. `Will a. Smith`

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
    Try
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT cfname, cmname, clname from candidate;"
        End With
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        With ComboBox1
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            .DataSource = dt
            .DisplayMember = "cfname"
            .ValueMember = "cfname"
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the values from the columns in your SQL command, like this:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cfname, cmname, clname) AS fullname FROM candidate;"
```

Then, set your `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties to that concatenated column, like this:

```
.DisplayMember = "fullname"
.ValueMember = "fullname"
```

Comment: also CONCAT_WS seems to be better when you have more than two fields to concatenate...

Comment: @Steve  Thanks again.  I'm not that familiar with MySql, so the help is appreciated.

Comment: thanks sir! but how do i put spaces appear in the combobox? when i add spaces in the select query, it doesn't change.

Comment: @SkyScraper That's strange.  Can you edit your question to show what you did and show what the new output is?

Comment: it's okay now, i just added the one you edited the CONCAT_WS(' ' thanks sir!